# Functions (mccollect, mcparallel, mc.reset.streem) missing from parallel package?

Tags: r, function, parallel-processing, package, multicore

I'm using the multiPIMboot() function from the multiPIM-package which in turn asks for the mc.reset.stream() and mcparallel() function. These seem to no longer be present in the parallel-package.

In the multiPIMboot() function the following bit of code gives the problem

```
parallel::mc.reset.stream()
jobs <- lapply(1:mc.num.jobs, function(x) parallel::mcparallel(run.one.job(x), 
                                                               name = x))
results.list <- parallel::mccollect(jobs)
```

The functions are in this list, but the links are dead

[file:///C:/Program%20Files/R/R-3.3.0/library/parallel/html/00Index.html](http://file:///C:/Program%20Files/R/R-3.3.0/library/parallel/html/00Index.html)

Via this list: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/00Index.html

I could access the help of mcparrallel and mccollect in which it states

> These functions are based on forking and so are not available on Windows.
>
> mcparallel starts a parallel R process which evaluates the given expression.
> mccollect collects results from one or more parallel processes.

But that doesn't really make sense to me as that would imply that the multiPIM doesn't work on Windows.

So now I would either like to get the parallel-functions  from somewhere (longshot probably) or adjust the code and make a customized multiPIMboot-function. But I don't know how.

Thanks in advance

PS. I could set the parallel computing option to FALSE but I am running large simulations which take ages and ages.